# Canvas Elements avoid Center

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I have been trying to get an array of circle to attract to the center of a canvas element but avoid a specific radius in middle. This gets them to move to the center thanks to this bit of code from codepen.io but I haven't been able to get them to avoid like a 300px radius in the middle. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// for each circle attraction to center
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   var c0 = circles[i];
   var dx = c0.x - canvas.center.x;
   var dy = c0.y - canvas.center.y;
   var f = 1 / c0.radius;
   c0.x -= dx * 0.5 * f;
   c0.y -= dy * 0.03;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to make happen to a circle when it hits the 300px middle radius: bounce off, stick to the outside, move around the circumference, disappear, something else?

Comment: @markE Currently the circles collide with each other using this [code](http://pastie.org/10375613). You can see a screenshot [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx7zRq6VPJISaHpMdEdZMGdaWU0/view?usp=sharing). I just can't seem to keep the circles from avoid the center equal to the top circle. But they just kinda float around similar to this on [codepen](http://codepen.io/scottcarlton/pen/jPgGzx).

Comment: This looks a fun issue. Could you put up an example on JSFiddle? It seems as though you'll need to calculate the distance between the center of each circle (the one in the middle and the one you want to be attracted to it) and stop it moving if the distance is greater than the radius of the center circle added to the radius of the other.

Comment: There is a staging site at dev.scottcarlton.io

Answer (score 0):

You can do via following thing.

First, a function use to fill a circle.

```
var fillCircle = function(x, y, radius)
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fill();
};
```

---

#### `clip()`

```
var clearCircle = function(x, y, radius)
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.clip();
    context.clearRect(x - radius - 1, y - radius - 1,
                      radius * 2 + 2, radius * 2 + 2);
};
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/DfWX7/4/).

---

#### `globalCompositeOperation`

```
var clearCircle = function(x, y, radius)
{
    context.save();
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fill();
    context.restore();
};
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/WWH8J/).

---

Both gave the desired result on screen.

Comment: Any reason why you deleted your previous answer on your other account?